How can we mount storage buckets where the names of the buckets are following a pattern
Say, I have ten thousand buckets of same naming pattern and rest all other buckets with different names. How can I mount only those buckets who are in the same pattern ,using wild cards?
For Example:
My Bucket are follwing the pattern in their names:
bucket-stroage-1
bucket-storage-2
bucket-storage-3
bucket-storage-4
and so on.
I want to use GCSFuse to mount these all buckets in my persistent volume Yaml.
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: gcs-fuse-csi-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: example-storage-class
  claimRef:
    namespace: NAMESPACE
    name: gcs-fuse-csi-static-pvc
  mountOptions:
    - implicit-dirs
  csi:
    driver: gcsfuse.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: PATTERN_BUCKET_NAME-*
    volumeAttributes:
      gcsfuseLoggingSeverity: warning

Is it possible ?
I am trying to mount a particular set of buckets as persistent volume , not all buckets,  in Google Kubernetes Cluster

Please consider asking system admin questions on serverfault.com, but please read their help pages to ensure that your question meets their site rules.


How can I mount only those buckets who are in the same pattern ,using wild cards?

GCSFuse (or cloud storage fuse) does not support mounting buckets with a name-pattern e.g. bucket-stroage-*, but only with full names e.g. bucket-stroage-7. However it also supports mounting all buckets (which you have the permissions to) to a root directory where any bucket can be accessed as a sub-directory. This is called dynamic mounting. refer doc for more details.
For dynamic mounting in GKE, you can pass bucket-name as _ . For this, set spec.volumes[n].csi.volumeAttributes.bucketName to _ in a CSI ephemeral storage volume, or spec.csi.volumeHandle to _ in a CSI persistent volume.
Note, even this way buckets still need to be referred to with their full name in the root directory, not with a pattern, as it mounts buckets with their full names as and when they are first accessed. But it should make it easier than having to declare all the buckets in the configuration.
